# Wrong detection in the same name functions

Tags: c++

I have two functions with same name and multiple signature as below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Function for bool data

void test(const bool &b) {
    wcout << L"bool data is : " << b << endl;
};

//Function for   wstring data

void test(const wstring &w) {
    wcout << L"wstring data is : " << w.c_str() << endl;
};

void main() {
    test(L"my string  data for test");
    test(true);
}
```

Why when i use the wstring value type `void test(const bool &b)`function executed?

Comment: Might be an outdated compiler that also accepts `void main()`. (Not really, but why is it still so prevalent).

Answer (score 4):

A wide string literal is of type `const wchar_t [N+1]`. When you pass it to `test`, there are two possible paths:

1. `const wchar_t[N+1]` -> `const wchar_t*` -> `bool`
2. `const wchar_t[N+1]` -> `const wchar_t*` -> `std::wstring`

The first version is chosen because overload resolution prefers the standard boolean conversion to `bool` is preferred to the user-defined conversion to `std::wstring`.

One possible solution would be to explicitly create the `std::wstring`, as [Martin suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38482953/496161), but I think this is likely to bite you again later on. I would instead either have two functions with different names to avoid the issue, or add an overload which takes a `const wchar_t*` and forwards on to the `std::wstring` version.

```
void test(const wchar_t* w) {
    test(std::wstring{w});   
}
```

Comment: That's a much clearer explanation of what I was trying to say.  Can I suggest adding my workround (add another overload force the "right" function to be called)?

Comment: In the second case, the sequence is `const wchar[N+1]` -> `const wchar *` -> `std::wstring`    (actually `wchar` should be `wchar_t`).    Essentially conversion of a pointer to a `bool` is preferred over a user-defined conversion (i.e. invoking the constructor of `std::wstring`).

Comment: Given how the `wstring` version is written, I'd do the forwarding the other way. Although that version is arguably broken.

Answer (score 3):

Your string literal is not a `wstring` but a `const wchar_t[]` which is more easily converted to a `bool` (via decay into a `const wchar_t*`) than a `wstring`.

Running your code in Visual Studios gave me this error:
`warning C4800: 'const wchar_t *' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)`
which gives a pretty much perfect explanation.

Comment: The string literal is not `const wchar_t*` either - it's an array of const `wchar_t` (not quite the same thing).

Comment: Correct. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3):

All answers being given, if you use c++14, you could just tweak the literal you pass in the first case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Function for bool data

void test(const bool b) {
    wcout << L"bool data is : " << b << endl;
};

//Function for   wstring data

void test(const wstring &w) {
    wcout << L"wstring data is : " << w.c_str() << endl;
};

int main() {
    test(L"my string  data for test"s);
    test(true);
    return 0;
}
```

[output](http://ideone.com/8YOiLs):

> wstring data is : my string  data for test
>   bool data is : 1

Answer (score 1):

You have been bitten by the rules for implicit type conversions.  The problem is that `L"my string data for test"` is neither a `bool` nor a `std::wstring`.  It is in fact a const array of `wchar_t`.

It can be converted to `bool` by array decays to pointer, followed by pointer to `bool` conversion (test if the pointer is null - it isn't).

It can be converted to `std::wstring` by calling the appropriate constructor.

Your problem is that the standard calls for the the compiler to choose the "wrong" one.

Probably your best bet is to write a suitable additional overload.  For example:

```
void test(const wchar_t* p)
{
   test(std::wstring(p));
}
```